# [getStream]Parameters for ranking in getStream

Tags: getstream-io

1) Is there any parameter available in stream which helps us in ranking the feeds according to the distance i.e. person getting feeds firstly for closer places and then for distant places in the feed ranking?

Comment: Need clarification for the distance. Could you expand and maybe give an example too? Thanks!

Comment: distance here is in the terms of geographical location. i.e the new feeds corresponding to the closer city appears before than that of the distant city in the feed ranking to the user.

Comment: Possible but not directly available. Please, contact to support for personalization.